# How to work out how many models GridSearchCV will train?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

How do you work out how many models SKLearn's GridSearchCV will train? In my case I am using the following parameters:

```
learning_rate_range = [0.01, 0.05, 0.1]
max_depth_range = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
min_child_weight_range = [6, 7, 8]
subsample_range = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
colsample_range = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

If, for example, you are using 3-fold cross-validation, how many models will be trained in total, and what is the general method used to work this out?

Comment: When using GridSearchCV with verbose param, the first line that you see will be this specific number that you have asked.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation: "GridSearchCV exhaustively considers all parameter combinations, while RandomizedSearchCV can sample a given number of candidates from a parameter space with a specified distribution.".

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html#grid-search

And an example of GridSearchCV in action:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-digits-py

If you pass all of the parameters above in one dictionary you will get 3x5x3x4x3 grid points and each point will be cross-validated 3 times.

Answer (score 4):

As @KRKirov said, the total number of parameters is simply the product of the individual levels of each parameter. SciKit learn provides a simple method to know the total number of parameters as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

parameters = {
learning_rate_range: [0.01, 0.05, 0.1]
max_depth_range: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
min_child_weight_range: [6, 7, 8]
subsample_range: [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
colsample_range: [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
}

grid = ParameterGrid(parameters)
# python 3.6+ for the f format
print (f"The total number of parameters-combinations is: {len(grid)}")
```

Please bear in mind that each parameters-combination is executed 5 times for cross-validations. Hence, the total executions will be `5 * len(grid)`